# Unit testing Raven and ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, ravendb

I'm starting a web app that will be using asp.net membership services (with a sql server backend) to look after users and RavenDb for everything else.

I'm new to unit testing and would appreciate it if I can run past you what I've got so far with one example method.

This is HelixManager

```
public class HelixManager:IDisposable
{
    private readonly IMembershipProvider _membership;
    private readonly IRepository _repos;

    public HelixManager()
    {
        _membership = new AspNetMembershipProvider(); 
        _repos = new RavenRepository();
    }

    public HelixManager(IMembershipProvider membershipProvider, IRepository repos) 
    { 
        _membership = membershipProvider;
        _repos = repos;
    }

    public User CreateAdmin(User newUser, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newUser.Email)) throw new ArgumentException("Email must be supplied");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentException("Password must be supplied");

        var memberId = _membership.CreateUser(newUser, password);

        if (memberId != null)
        {
            _membership.AddToRole(newUser, "Admin");

            newUser.Type = UserType.Admin;
            newUser.MemberId = memberId;

            _repos.Store<User>(newUser);
        }

        return newUser;
    }
```

This is IMembershipProvider

```
public interface IMembershipProvider
{
    string CreateUser(User newUser, string password);
    void AddToRole(User user, string rolename);
}
```

and the implementation AspNetMembershipProvider

```
public class AspNetMembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider
{
    public string CreateUser(User newUser, string password)
    {
        MembershipCreateStatus status;
        MembershipUser memUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(newUser.Email, password, newUser.Email, "", "", true, out status);
        return memUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    }

    public void AddToRole(User user, string role)
    {
        Roles.AddUserToRole(user.Email, role);
    }
}
```

This is IRepository

```
public interface IRepository
{
    T Store<T>(T item);
}
```

and it's implementation

```
public class RavenRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly DocumentStore _store;

    public RavenRepository()
    {
        _store = new DocumentStore { DefaultDatabase = "Helix", Url = "http://localhost:8080" };
        _store.Initialize();
    }

    public T Store<T>(T item)
    {
        using (var session = _store.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(item);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

In my test project, I have created fake implementations of both of these:

FakeMembershipProvider:

```
class FakeMembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider
{
    public string CreateUser(User newUser, string password)
    {
        CreatedUser = true;
        return newUser.Email == "email@example.com" ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : null;
    }

    public void AddToRole(User user, string rolename)
    {
        AddedToRole = true;
    }

    public bool AddedToRole;
    public bool CreatedUser;
}
```

and FakeRepository:

```
public class FakeRepository : IRepository
{
    public T Store<T>(T item)
    {
        StoreCalled = true;
        return item;
    }

    public bool StoreCalled;
}
```

The tests are then approx as follows:

```
public class UserManagementTests
{
    private readonly HelixManager _hm;
    private readonly IMembershipProvider _fakeMembershipProvider;
    private readonly IRepository _fakeRepository;

    public UserManagementTests()
    {
        _fakeMembershipProvider = new FakeMembershipProvider();
        _fakeRepository = new FakeRepository();
        _hm = new HelixManager(_fakeMembershipProvider, _fakeRepository);       
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateAdminReturnsValidAdminUser()
    {

        var newUser = new User
                           {
                               AvatarName = "fred",
                               Email = "email@example.com",
                               Forename = "Fred",
                               Surname = "Jones"
                           };

        _hm.CreateAdmin(newUser, "password");

        Assert.IsNotNull(newUser.MemberId);
        Assert.AreEqual(UserType.Admin, newUser.Type);
    }
```

What am I asking is before I get any further down this line, is this the right way to be going about this?  Or are there better ways of doing this?

I also plan to have an IntegrationTests project that will use a real db and a real RavenDb instance to test end to end.

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with that approach.  You could go the route of using a Mocking tool ([Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks.ashx), [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/)) to create your fakes instead of doing it by hand, but that is really a matter of personal preference and your personal comfort-level with the tools.

Your test is clearly structured, asserting based on state (which is a good thing), and your not trying to test too many things at once, which is a common mistake (even for those of us who have been doing this for a while).

If you haven't seen it yet, I can highly recommend [Roy Osherove's](http://weblogs.asp.net/ROsherove/) [Art of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/), which has a lot of very good information about unit testing, including things like keeping tests clean, how to deal with less-testable areas of code, etc.

I say keep truckin' :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Book ordered. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your tests are look absolutely fine to me. Right approach (mocks) right way (AAA).

Go ahead :)

Answer (score 2):

My problem is actually with this:

> I'm starting a web app that will be
>   using asp.net membership services
>   (with a sql server backend) to look
>   after users and RavenDb for everything
>   else.

Why are you doing this?
It would be easier to make everything in RavenDB, and your unit testing issue would be as simple as new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true }

Comment: We are using the membership services because that's what we are used to and we're happy with how it works (and we already have a SQL server available to us) but the EmbeddableDocumentStore suggestion is fantastic for the ravendb bits! :)

Comment: +! For Ayende's answer. Avoid ASP.NET MEMBERSHIP like the plague! Do. Not. Use. It's soooo over-engineered it's disgusting. You can roll your own really simply AND avoid having to use Sql Server. RavenDB can handle user management easily.